# AWS Lambda Node.js error - Runtime.ImportModuleError

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

My `sensor-processor-v3-dev-wifiConnector` lambda function handler is `src/wifi.connector`.

Inside my `serverless-v3.zip` file where I've deployed all the webpack compiled JavaScript code the folder structure is the same as `src/*.js`.

[image]

When I run the script from AWS CLI:

```bash
aws lambda invoke --function-name sensor-processor-v3-dev-wifiConnector output.json
```

The output is:

```json
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'wifiConnector'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
    "trace": [
        "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'wifiConnector'",
        "Require stack:",
        "- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
        "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1061:17)",
        "    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1093:21)",
        "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1256:23)",
        "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1262:1"
    ]
}
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: Please include your source file structure (screenshot or text) and also the code which is importing `wifiConnector`, it's hard to say for sure what's happening based only on the info provided.

Comment: `wifiConnector` is not imported in anywhere. I built all my functions with webpack and zip them inside `src` folder. Then I renamed the zip file `sensor-processor-v3.zip`. Then I uploaded it to S3. From the lambda function the handler is set to `src/wifi.connector`. `src` is the folder inside the zip, `wifi` is the name of the javascript file and `connector` is the function name. Am I right?